# Family of maps from inverse system to another space

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

The [universal property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit#General_definition) of an inverse limit $\lim_{\leftarrow} X_\alpha$ allows one to define from a compatible system of maps $\psi_\alpha: Y \rightarrow X_\alpha$ a unique map $\psi: Y \rightarrow \lim_{\leftarrow} X_\alpha$ making the obvious diagrams commutative.

I'm interested in the case of maps in the opposite direction, i.e. when does the family $\phi_\alpha: X_\alpha \rightarrow Z$ defines a map $\phi: \lim_{\leftarrow} X_\alpha \rightarrow Z$?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it will certainly be the case whenever you'll have $\phi_\alpha = \phi_\beta\circ \psi^\alpha_\beta$, where $\psi^\alpha_\beta:X\alpha\to X_\beta$ is the bonding map of the inverese system $\{X_\alpha\}$, $\alpha \ge\beta$.

In fact this follows by the same argument which one can use to prove the case you provided as motivation... You can represent $Z$ as the limit of the trivial inverse system $\{Z_\alpha\}$, where $\alpha$ belongs to the same indexing set as in the case for $\{X_\alpha\}$, all $Z_\alpha$ are $Z$ itself, and the respective projections are identities. Then if $\phi_\alpha = \phi_\beta\circ \psi^\alpha_\beta$ holds, your family of mappings satisfies the definition of a morphism ov inverse systems over the same indexing set. Every such morphism has the limit.